# Sum of anonymous functions in Octave

Tags: octave

I am trying to sum up an anonymous, 2-variable, function by adding it to itself ( something like += operator in C or Java). The example code is as follows :

```
f = @(x, y) 0;
for iter = 1: 10
    a = @(x) x^2;
    b = @(y) cos(y);
    c = @(x, y) a(x) + b(y);
    f = @(x, y) f(x, y) + c(x, y);
end
```

Is it possible to do it like this or the syntax is bad ? Is there a more efficient or reasonable way to do it ? Ty in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite common to have anonymous functions that are built on top of other anonymous functions.  It looks like `f` is the result of a sum of other anonymous functions so `f` should be fine and good to use once you reach that statement in your loop.  However, the code you have written doesn't use any of the resulting anonymous functions after you create them.  I'd also recommend using element-wise operations to ensure that multiple inputs (matrices / vectors for example) can be included.

Therefore:

```
f = @(x, y) 0;
for iter = 1: 10
    a = @(x) x.^2; % Change
    b = @(y) cos(y);
    c = @(x, y) a(x) + b(y);
    f = @(x, y) f(x, y) + c(x, y);
end
```

Here's a small reproducible example showing what the chain of statements would look like at one iteration, then using the resulting final function `f` at the end:

```
>> f = @(x,y) 0
f =

@(x, y) 0

>> a = @(x) x.^2
a =

@(x) x .^ 2

>> b = @(y) cos(y)
b =

@(y) cos (y)

>> c = @(x, y) a(x) + b(y)
c =

@(x, y) a (x) + b (y)

>> f = @(x, y) f(x, y) + c(x, y)
f =

@(x, y) f (x, y) + c (x, y)

>> f(0.5, 7)
ans =  1.0039
>>
```